# Short story about an Earth ambassador who must solve a murder on a planet where all people wear masks and sing

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking for a science fiction short story with the word "mask" in the title, probably from the '80s. It follows an Earth ambassador who arrives on a new planet where all people wear masks and sing as a language. A fellow Earthman is murdered and he has to solve the crime, all while trying not to offend the sensitive local population.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Murder investigation on planet where people express their feelings with musical instruments worn on a necklace](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/231217/murder-investigation-on-planet-where-people-express-their-feelings-with-musical)

Comment: @Alith site policy is that we don't close story id questions as duplicates until both have accepted answers.

Comment: @OrganicMarble, apologies, you're right of course, I forgot that we waited for confirmation.

Comment: And, FWIW, @Alan, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 20):

This is [The Moon Moth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Moon_Moth) by Jack Vance. It has been identified before in [Murder investigation on planet where people express their feelings with musical instruments worn on a necklace](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/231217/murder-investigation-on-planet-where-people-express-their-feelings-with-musical)

> Edwer Thissell, the new consul from Earth to the planet Sirene, has trouble adjusting to the local culture. The Sirenese cover their faces and heads with exquisitely crafted masks that indicate their social status (strakh) and mood. They also communicate by singing, accompanying themselves with one of a score of musical instruments, selected based on the social situation and feelings. Furthermore, errors of etiquette may prove fatal. Thissell is a clumsy musician and lacks confidence in the alien society, so he is forced to wear a lowly Moon Moth mask.

Thissell is on the planet to hunt an assassin, and the murder is committed by the assassin. Thissell has to catch the assassin without offending the Sirenese.

Comment: I upvoted because "The Moon Moth" was my immediate thought.